# Set the value of a property of an object using Reflection, where this object is the property of another object

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have to set the value of all properties of objects being creating in run time, where the class will also be just known in run time. I am using `Generics (<T>)`, `Reflection` and `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)) as T` to get the type of class, create  an object, iterate over all its public properties and assign them a value. The problem comes when a property of my class is another class: I am able to see its properties but I don't know how to use the `propInfo.SetValue(myObj, newValue, null)`.

There will be a lot of different classes and 'subclasses' used by the properties, so it will not be possible to defined in advance a fixed pattern of the data, and therefore everything has to be done in run time.

How can I set the value of a property of an object using `Reflection`, where this object is the property of another object, being all these only known in run time? I am in `Visual Studio 2022 (17.5.0 Preview 6.0)`.

Thanks in advance!

```
public class MyClass1
{
    public int? Prop1 { get; set; }
    public Child1? Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass2
{
    public int? Prop1 { get; set; }
    public Child1? Prop2 { get; set; }
    public Child2? Prop3 { get; set; }
}

public class Child1
{
    public double? Prop1 { get; set; }
}

public class Child2
{
    public string? Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int? Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: just use `Activator.CreateInstance(propertyInfo.PropertyType)`.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain thanks, I was able to make my code work with this suggestion :-)